# ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', volume must be a mapping, not an array

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am getting this error (ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', volume must be a mapping, not an array) when I am running "docker-compose up" command.

### My docker-compose.yml file looks like this.

```
version: '2'
web:
build: .
ports:
- "5000:5000"
volumes:
- .:/code
ngnix:
image: "ngnix:alpine"
```

---

### and my docker file looks like this

```
FROM alpine:3.5

MAINTAINER NGINX Docker Maintainers "docker-maint@nginx.com"

ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.13.3

RUN GPG_KEYS=B0F4253373F8F6F510D42178520A9993A1C052F8 \
        && CONFIG="\
                --prefix=/etc/nginx \
                --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
                --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules \
                --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
                --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
                --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
                --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
                --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock \
                --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp \
                --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp \
                --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp \
                --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp \
                --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp \
                --user=nginx \
                --group=nginx \
                --with-http_ssl_module \
                --with-http_realip_module \
                --with-http_addition_module \
                --with-http_sub_module \
                --with-http_dav_module \
                --with-http_flv_module \
                --with-http_mp4_module \
                --with-http_gunzip_module \
                --with-http_gzip_static_module \
                --with-http_random_index_module \
                --with-http_secure_link_module \
                --with-http_stub_status_module \
                --with-http_auth_request_module \
                --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic \
                --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic \
                --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic \
                --with-http_perl_module=dynamic \
                --with-threads \
                --with-stream \
                --with-stream_ssl_module \
                --with-stream_ssl_preread_module \
                --with-stream_realip_module \
                --with-stream_geoip_module=dynamic \
                --with-http_slice_module \
                --with-mail \
                --with-mail_ssl_module \
                --with-compat \
                --with-file-aio \
                --with-http_v2_module \
        " \
        && addgroup -S nginx \
        && adduser -D -S -h /var/cache/nginx -s /sbin/nologin -G nginx nginx \
        && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
                gcc \
                libc-dev \
                make \
                openssl-dev \
                pcre-dev \
                zlib-dev \
                linux-headers \
                curl \
                gnupg \
                libxslt-dev \
                gd-dev \
                geoip-dev \
                perl-dev \
        && curl -fSL http://nginx.org/download/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION.tar.gz -o nginx.tar.gz \
        && curl -fSL http://nginx.org/download/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION.tar.gz.asc  -o nginx.tar.gz.asc \
        && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
        && found=''; \
        for server in \
                ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net \
                hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 \
                hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 \
                pgp.mit.edu \
        ; do \
                echo "Fetching GPG key $GPG_KEYS from $server"; \
                gpg --keyserver "$server" --keyserver-options timeout=10 --recv-keys "$GPG_KEYS" && found=yes && break; \
        done; \
        test -z "$found" && echo >&2 "error: failed to fetch GPG key $GPG_KEYS" && exit 1; \
        gpg --batch --verify nginx.tar.gz.asc nginx.tar.gz \
        && rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" nginx.tar.gz.asc \
        && mkdir -p /usr/src \
        && tar -zxC /usr/src -f nginx.tar.gz \
        && rm nginx.tar.gz \
        && cd /usr/src/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION \
        && ./configure $CONFIG --with-debug \
        && make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) \
        && mv objs/nginx objs/nginx-debug \
        && mv objs/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so objs/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module-debug.so \
        && mv objs/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so objs/ngx_http_image_filter_module-debug.so \
        && mv objs/ngx_http_geoip_module.so objs/ngx_http_geoip_module-debug.so \
        && mv objs/ngx_http_perl_module.so objs/ngx_http_perl_module-debug.so \
        && mv objs/ngx_stream_geoip_module.so objs/ngx_stream_geoip_module-debug.so \
        && ./configure $CONFIG \
        && make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) \
        && make install \
        && rm -rf /etc/nginx/html/ \
        && mkdir /etc/nginx/conf.d/ \
        && mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html/ \
        && install -m644 html/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/ \
        && install -m644 html/50x.html /usr/share/nginx/html/ \
        && install -m755 objs/nginx-debug /usr/sbin/nginx-debug \
        && install -m755 objs/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module-debug.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module-debug.so \
        && install -m755 objs/ngx_http_image_filter_module-debug.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module-debug.so \
        && install -m755 objs/ngx_http_geoip_module-debug.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module-debug.so \
        && install -m755 objs/ngx_http_perl_module-debug.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_perl_module-debug.so \
        && install -m755 objs/ngx_stream_geoip_module-debug.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_geoip_module-debug.so \
        && ln -s ../../usr/lib/nginx/modules /etc/nginx/modules \
        && strip /usr/sbin/nginx* \
        && strip /usr/lib/nginx/modules/*.so \
        && rm -rf /usr/src/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION \
        \
        # Bring in gettext so we can get `envsubst`, then throw
        # the rest away. To do this, we need to install `gettext`
        # then move `envsubst` out of the way so `gettext` can
        # be deleted completely, then move `envsubst` back.
        && apk add --no-cache --virtual .gettext gettext \
        && mv /usr/bin/envsubst /tmp/ \
        \
        && runDeps="$( \
                scanelf --needed --nobanner /usr/sbin/nginx /usr/lib/nginx/modules/*.so /tmp/envsubst \
                        | awk '{ gsub(/,/, "\nso:", $2); print "so:" $2 }' \
                        | sort -u \
                        | xargs -r apk info --installed \
                        | sort -u \
        )" \
        && apk add --no-cache --virtual .nginx-rundeps $runDeps \
        && apk del .build-deps \
        && apk del .gettext \
        && mv /tmp/envsubst /usr/local/bin/ \
        \
        # forward request and error logs to docker log collector
        && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
        && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx.vh.default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

RUN sed -i "s/server {/server {\n \n  error_log syslog:server=loggly;\n    access_log syslog:server=loggly;\n/" /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

---

What can i do for this, Should there be change id .yml file or in Dockerfile

Comment: Is your YAML file really indented like this or is this a copy/paste issue?

Comment: Actually i want to create an YAML file but according to the Dockerfile i tried doing it in several ways but the same error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your docker-compose.yml file needs to be indented properly - spaces denote structure in a YAML file.  I suspect you'll want something like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
    - .:/code
  ngnix:
    image: "ngnix:alpine"
```

Without the indentation you'll get the error message

Comment: Yup, Worked for me Thanks @benny23